# run-python and interactively choose working directory

Tags: python

When starting an R process using [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) (`M-x R`) you are interactively asked for a working directory.

To replicate this behaviour for python I have been opening up some random file in the directory I want to start python and then calling `run-python`, which is not as convenient. My question is - is there a way to replicate the R behaviour? That is, call `my-run-python` (or whatever) which prompts for a directory and then starts python there?

Comment: Why not copypaste the already existing solution? To do that, use apropos command, or similar, to find the help file for the `M-x R' command, which should point to the source code file. Check that file, it should contain all the code which needs only a little changing for you to run a python session the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user3496846. I've had a look at [the source on github](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/44f27b83dfe92b679e607742a99640219776086e/lisp/ess-r-mode.el#L464) but unfortunately it is a bit beyond me right now.